# Kivy buildozer: Set the api level from 19 to 28 failed

Tags: android, python, kivy

I'm having problems with buildozer after adding these changes to the buildozer.spec... I tried to solve the problem with the help on https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/pull/1381

### android.api = 28 android.minapi = 21 android.sdk = 24 android.ndk = 17c android.ndk_path = "/media/work/android-ndk-r17c"

---

I get this error when I tried compiling the code with buildozer 2.0

```
Debian `dpkg' package management program version 1.17.5 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /usr/local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run "pip install -q --user 'appdirs' 'colorama>=0.3.3' 'jinja2' 'six' 'enum34;python_version<'3.4'' 'sh>=1.10'"
# Cwd None
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 257, in run
    InstallRequirement.from_line(name, None))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 172, in from_line
    return cls(req, comes_from, url=url, prereleases=prereleases)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 70, in __init__
    req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2667, in parse
    reqs = list(parse_requirements(s))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2605, in parse_requirements
    line, p, specs = scan_list(VERSION,LINE_END,line,p,(1,2),"version spec")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2573, in scan_list
    raise ValueError("Expected "+item_name+" in",line,"at",line[p:])
ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'enum34;python_version<3.4', 'at', ';python_version<3.4')

Storing debug log for failure in /tmp/tmpPaMFYm
# Command failed: pip install -q --user 'appdirs' 'colorama>=0.3.3' 'jinja2' 'six' 'enum34;python_version<'3.4'' 'sh>=1.10'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

**Update:**

```
  STDOUT:
Android NDK: APP_PLATFORM not set. Defaulting to minimum supported version android-14.    
jni/Android.mk:11: Extraneous text after `ifeq' directive
/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r17c/build/core/build-binary.mk:688: Android NDK: Module cjpeg depends on undefined modules: cutils    
/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r17c/build/core/build-binary.mk:701: *** Android NDK: Aborting (set APP_ALLOW_MISSING_DEPS=true to allow missing dependencies)    .  Stop.


  STDERR:

# Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=hoto --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy==master,plyer,openssl,pil --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/kivy/Desktop/Hoto/.buildozer/android/platform/build"
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
kivy@kivyvm:~/Desktop/Hoto$
```

**2nd Update:**
I solved the above error by setting APP_ALLOW_MISSING_DEPS=true in Application.mk file and by removing the word libcutils in jpeg/build-static.patch

I think this might be a p4a error:

```
<instantiation>:6:5: error: unknown directive
    .func jsimd_idct_islow_neon
    ^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:199:1: note: while in macro instantiation
asm_function jsimd_idct_islow_neon
^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:658:1: error: unknown directive
.endfunc
^
<instantiation>:6:5: error: unknown directive
    .func jsimd_idct_ifast_neon
    ^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:703:1: note: while in macro instantiation
asm_function jsimd_idct_ifast_neon
^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:882:1: error: unknown directive
.endfunc
^
<instantiation>:6:5: error: unknown directive
    .func jsimd_idct_4x4_neon
    ^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:996:1: note: while in macro instantiation
asm_function jsimd_idct_4x4_neon
^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:1107:1: error: unknown directive
.endfunc
^
<instantiation>:6:5: error: unknown directive
    .func jsimd_idct_2x2_neon
    ^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:1156:1: note: while in macro instantiation
asm_function jsimd_idct_2x2_neon
^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:1261:1: error: unknown directive
.endfunc
^
<instantiation>:6:5: error: unknown directive
    .func jsimd_ycc_extrgb_convert_neon
    ^
<instantiation>:82:1: note: while in macro instantiation
asm_function jsimd_ycc_extrgb_convert_neon
^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:1554:1: note: while in macro instantiation
generate_jsimd_ycc_rgb_convert_neon extrgb, 24, 0, 1, 2
^
<instantiation>:190:1: error: unknown directive
.endfunc
^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:1554:1: note: while in macro instantiation
generate_jsimd_ycc_rgb_convert_neon extrgb, 24, 0, 1, 2
^
<instantiation>:6:5: error: unknown directive
    .func jsimd_ycc_extbgr_convert_neon
    ^
<instantiation>:82:1: note: while in macro instantiation
asm_function jsimd_ycc_extbgr_convert_neon
^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:1555:1: note: while in macro instantiation
generate_jsimd_ycc_rgb_convert_neon extbgr, 24, 2, 1, 0
^
<instantiation>:190:1: error: unknown directive
.endfunc
^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:1555:1: note: while in macro instantiation
generate_jsimd_ycc_rgb_convert_neon extbgr, 24, 2, 1, 0
^
<instantiation>:6:5: error: unknown directive
    .func jsimd_ycc_extrgbx_convert_neon
    ^
<instantiation>:82:1: note: while in macro instantiation
asm_function jsimd_ycc_extrgbx_convert_neon
^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:1556:1: note: while in macro instantiation
generate_jsimd_ycc_rgb_convert_neon extrgbx, 32, 0, 1, 2
^
<instantiation>:190:1: error: unknown directive
.endfunc
^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:1556:1: note: while in macro instantiation
generate_jsimd_ycc_rgb_convert_neon extrgbx, 32, 0, 1, 2
^
<instantiation>:6:5: error: unknown directive
    .func jsimd_ycc_extbgrx_convert_neon
    ^
<instantiation>:82:1: note: while in macro instantiation
asm_function jsimd_ycc_extbgrx_convert_neon
^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:1557:1: note: while in macro instantiation
generate_jsimd_ycc_rgb_convert_neon extbgrx, 32, 2, 1, 0
^
<instantiation>:190:1: error: unknown directive
.endfunc
^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:1557:1: note: while in macro instantiation
generate_jsimd_ycc_rgb_convert_neon extbgrx, 32, 2, 1, 0
^
<instantiation>:6:5: error: unknown directive
    .func jsimd_ycc_extxbgr_convert_neon
    ^
<instantiation>:82:1: note: while in macro instantiation
asm_function jsimd_ycc_extxbgr_convert_neon
^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:1558:1: note: while in macro instantiation
generate_jsimd_ycc_rgb_convert_neon extxbgr, 32, 3, 2, 1
^
<instantiation>:190:1: error: unknown directive
.endfunc
^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:1558:1: note: while in macro instantiation
generate_jsimd_ycc_rgb_convert_neon extxbgr, 32, 3, 2, 1
^
<instantiation>:6:5: error: unknown directive
    .func jsimd_ycc_extxrgb_convert_neon
    ^
<instantiation>:82:1: note: while in macro instantiation
asm_function jsimd_ycc_extxrgb_convert_neon
^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:1559:1: note: while in macro instantiation
generate_jsimd_ycc_rgb_convert_neon extxrgb, 32, 1, 2, 3
^
<instantiation>:190:1: error: unknown directive
.endfunc
^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:1559:1: note: while in macro instantiation
generate_jsimd_ycc_rgb_convert_neon extxrgb, 32, 1, 2, 3
^
<instantiation>:6:5: error: unknown directive
    .func jsimd_extrgb_ycc_convert_neon
    ^
<instantiation>:99:1: note: while in macro instantiation
asm_function jsimd_extrgb_ycc_convert_neon
^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:1864:1: note: while in macro instantiation
generate_jsimd_rgb_ycc_convert_neon extrgb, 24, 0, 1, 2
^
<instantiation>:203:1: error: unknown directive
.endfunc
^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:1864:1: note: while in macro instantiation
generate_jsimd_rgb_ycc_convert_neon extrgb, 24, 0, 1, 2
^
<instantiation>:6:5: error: unknown directive
    .func jsimd_extbgr_ycc_convert_neon
    ^
<instantiation>:99:1: note: while in macro instantiation
asm_function jsimd_extbgr_ycc_convert_neon
^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:1865:1: note: while in macro instantiation
generate_jsimd_rgb_ycc_convert_neon extbgr, 24, 2, 1, 0
^
<instantiation>:203:1: error: unknown directive
.endfunc
^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:1865:1: note: while in macro instantiation
generate_jsimd_rgb_ycc_convert_neon extbgr, 24, 2, 1, 0
^
<instantiation>:6:5: error: unknown directive
    .func jsimd_extrgbx_ycc_convert_neon
    ^
<instantiation>:99:1: note: while in macro instantiation
asm_function jsimd_extrgbx_ycc_convert_neon
^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:1866:1: note: while in macro instantiation
generate_jsimd_rgb_ycc_convert_neon extrgbx, 32, 0, 1, 2
^
<instantiation>:203:1: error: unknown directive
.endfunc
^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:1866:1: note: while in macro instantiation
generate_jsimd_rgb_ycc_convert_neon extrgbx, 32, 0, 1, 2
^
<instantiation>:6:5: error: unknown directive
    .func jsimd_extbgrx_ycc_convert_neon
    ^
<instantiation>:99:1: note: while in macro instantiation
asm_function jsimd_extbgrx_ycc_convert_neon
^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:1867:1: note: while in macro instantiation
generate_jsimd_rgb_ycc_convert_neon extbgrx, 32, 2, 1, 0
^
<instantiation>:203:1: error: unknown directive
.endfunc
^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:1867:1: note: while in macro instantiation
generate_jsimd_rgb_ycc_convert_neon extbgrx, 32, 2, 1, 0
^
<instantiation>:6:5: error: unknown directive
    .func jsimd_extxbgr_ycc_convert_neon
    ^
<instantiation>:99:1: note: while in macro instantiation
asm_function jsimd_extxbgr_ycc_convert_neon
^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:1868:1: note: while in macro instantiation
generate_jsimd_rgb_ycc_convert_neon extxbgr, 32, 3, 2, 1
^
<instantiation>:203:1: error: unknown directive
.endfunc
^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:1868:1: note: while in macro instantiation
generate_jsimd_rgb_ycc_convert_neon extxbgr, 32, 3, 2, 1
^
<instantiation>:6:5: error: unknown directive
    .func jsimd_extxrgb_ycc_convert_neon
    ^
<instantiation>:99:1: note: while in macro instantiation
asm_function jsimd_extxrgb_ycc_convert_neon
^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:1869:1: note: while in macro instantiation
generate_jsimd_rgb_ycc_convert_neon extxrgb, 32, 1, 2, 3
^
<instantiation>:203:1: error: unknown directive
.endfunc
^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:1869:1: note: while in macro instantiation
generate_jsimd_rgb_ycc_convert_neon extxrgb, 32, 1, 2, 3
^
<instantiation>:6:5: error: unknown directive
    .func jsimd_convsamp_neon
    ^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:1883:1: note: while in macro instantiation
asm_function jsimd_convsamp_neon
^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:1935:1: error: unknown directive
.endfunc
^
<instantiation>:6:5: error: unknown directive
    .func jsimd_fdct_ifast_neon
    ^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:1963:1: note: while in macro instantiation
asm_function jsimd_fdct_ifast_neon
^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:2058:1: error: unknown directive
.endfunc
^
<instantiation>:6:5: error: unknown directive
    .func jsimd_quantize_neon
    ^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:2074:1: note: while in macro instantiation
asm_function jsimd_quantize_neon
^
jni/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.S:2159:1: error: unknown directive
.endfunc
^
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/simd/simd/jsimd_arm_neon.o] Error 1


  STDERR:
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=hoto --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy==master,plyer,openssl,pil --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/kivy/Desktop/Hoto/.buildozer/android/platform/build"
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Comment: I think perhaps your version of setuptools (or distutils?) is too old.

Comment: @inclement thank you, I ran `sudo pip install -upgrade setuptools`, and downloaded API 28 from android sdk manager. Please look at the edits I made for the new error. `Android NDK: APP_PLATFORM not set. Defaulting to minimum supported version android-14`

Comment: @inclement,  I solved the above problem, but adding p4a.branch = master to buildozer.spec gives me a new error (see 2nd update)

Comment: p4a already sets APP_ALLOW_MISSING_DEPS, I don't know why this has come up for you.

Comment: @inclement I have tried everything I can, but still no luck... Thank you

Comment: @inclement the build was successful after taking out pil, and openssl from the requirements in buildozer.spec, but the app fails on startup. `ImportError: No module named android`