# Is it even possible to package a kivy app to apk?

Tags: android, python, kivy

So I have been at this for a couple of days now trying to get my app to run on my phone. I've invested more hours in trying to create an apk than actually spent learning some kivy and making the application. I tried using kivy launcher to just launch the app but after hours on that I figured may as well just try and do it the hard way. And now I'm attempting to use a VM and buildozer to create the apk. I feel like I hit a roadblock at every turn. At this point I am starting to feel like it is just not possible with the current information and resources available? Has anybody been able to successfully package and create an apk through a VM with buildozer? If so, was it a Python3 app?

I followed all of the instructions to the letter and I am still getting the same old errors.

```
Welcome to the Buildozer Virtual Machine.
Please see ~/Desktop/README.txt for more information
kivy@kivy-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/MyApp$ buildozer android debug
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Read available permissions from api-versions.xml
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian `dpkg' package management program version 1.17.5 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /usr/local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run 'git clone -b master --single-branch https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android.git python-for-android'
# Cwd /home/kivy/Desktop/MyApp/.buildozer/android/platform
Cloning into 'python-for-android'...
# Run '/usr/bin/python -m pip install -q --user \'appdirs\' \'colorama>=0.3.3\' \'jinja2\' \'six\' \'enum34; python_version<"3.4"\' \'sh>=1.10; sys_platform!="nt"\''
# Cwd None
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 257, in run
    InstallRequirement.from_line(name, None))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 172, in from_line
    return cls(req, comes_from, url=url, prereleases=prereleases)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 70, in __init__
    req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2667, in parse
    reqs = list(parse_requirements(s))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2605, in parse_requirements
    line, p, specs = scan_list(VERSION,LINE_END,line,p,(1,2),"version spec")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2573, in scan_list
    raise ValueError("Expected "+item_name+" in",line,"at",line[p:])
ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'enum34; python_version<"3.4"', 'at', '; python_version<"3.4"')

Storing debug log for failure in /tmp/tmpWAP4Iu
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pip install -q --user 'appdirs' 'colorama>=0.3.3' 'jinja2' 'six' 'enum34; python_version<"3.4"' 'sh>=1.10; sys_platform!="nt"'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I followed all of the instructions for CrystaX and I am still getting nowhere. I would REALLY appreciate some help with this as I am completely out of ideas here.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I got a test app into a .apk back in August 2018 (started developing more on iOS using kivy-ios). I wrote up a doc about how to do it for myself using the VM and buildozer. One of the requirements I have written down was to use python 2.7 - so that could be a dilemma for you (not sure if that's changed since august!). IT IS POSSIBLE! Keep trying and you'll get it. I always say the hardest part of coding is installing / packaging

Comment: hello! thank you for your response. I appreciate it. So when you say that python 2.7 is a requirement, do you mean that I have to create the program using python 2.7? or i have to have python 2.7 installed?

Comment: I think I meant that your program needs to be able to be run using python 2.7. The virtual machine should have everything you need pre-installed, so I don't think you have to do any additional installs yourself on the VM. Your issue does appear to be version related given this line in your error: `ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'enum34; python_version<"3.4"', 'at', '; python_version<"3.4"')` but not sure exactly what to do about that at the moment

Comment: Read through this question too, looks related to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53380201/kivy-buildozer-set-the-api-level-from-19-to-28-failed

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to respond. I will see if i can get the app running in 2.7 and see if that solves the issue. Thank you for your time.

Comment: So i converted my file to Python2 by using 3to2 but I still get the same error. I really wish they would give more information in these logs. I've tried everything that I can at this point and have no way of knowing what the problem is.

Comment: Did you read through that question I linked?

Comment: I read through it. It looks like initially he had a simliar error to mine but fixed it by setting APP_ALLOW_MISSING_DEPS=true in Application.mk file and by removing the word libcutils in jpeg/build-static.patch. Not exactly sure what that means but it seems to have introduced more errors. It does not seem like he ever came up with a fix.

Comment: I also tried manually installing 'appdirs' 'colorama>=0.3.3' 'jinja2' 'six' 'enum34; with no luck. I've searched google for my particular error message but without a specific problem to search for, I've also had no luck

Comment: Hmm, okay, reading the error more closely, it looks like it's trying to find a string `version spec` in some kind of config file, but the config file says `python_version` instead of `version spec`. Possibly a mixup since there is active development going on. Try editing line 2573 of the file `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py` to say `version spec` instead of `python_version`

Comment: Hmm, the code for configuration actually does say 'version spec' : I think it's a variable definition. This seems to be where things fail for me:::  

match = ITEM(line,p)
            if not match:
                raise ValueError("Expected "+item_name+" in",line,"at",line[p:])

:::::which seems to be a result of this not matching up::::

 line, p, specs = scan_list(VERSION,LINE_END,line,p,(1,2),"version spec")
        specs = [(op,safe_version(val)) for op,val in specs]
        yield Requirement(project_name, specs, extras)

Comment: Try tinkering with that maybe? Like overwriting the variable definition or something? Pretty sure the strings should match up. Worst case is you screw up your VM and redownload it, right?

Comment: I actually figured it out thanks to you suggesting i look into that .py file. Helped me to figure out the exact error being thrown. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was just that I needed to upgrade pip. Apparently, the one preinstalled with the VM provided by kivy is no longer feasible.

just use:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Ah, what a simple answer. So glad I could help you find the right direction! Were you able to get it all packaged or did you run into another error?

Comment: Lol another error. But this time it's that I don't have enough space allocated to the VM to run buildozer. Shouldn't be too much of a problem.. I hope.